# Completion of spaces of discrete signals w.r.t different norms. Conditions for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

**Question:**
For each of the three norms on $C_c(\Bbb{N},\Bbb{R})$ (space of compact functions from $\Bbb{N}$ to $\Bbb{R}$), the completions with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$, $\|\cdot\|_2$, $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ can be characterized as the space of real-valued signals on $\Bbb{N}$ with the condition that some quantity (defined in terms of values of the functions) converges. Determine these convergence conditions. For each pair of completions, determine which one contains the other, or say if neither one contains the other.

**Start:**
I know the definition of a completion of a metric space is that it is a metric space for which each cauchy sequence converges in that space, and contains every element in the original metric space.

But I don't know how to find the completion of a metric space or what the conditions for convergence would be.

Comment: I know what the answer is.  But I don't know how to get to that answer unless you already know about $c_0$, $\ell^1$ and $\ell^2$.  Do you know about them?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but $\mathit{l}^p$ is the space of functions $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)^p$ converges? and $\mathit{c}_{0}$ is the space of those discrete with only finitely many non-zero points?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Perfect! I should be able to follow your solution then. Please post it whenever you get the chance :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a well known theorem that $\ell^1$, $\ell^2$, and $c_0$ are complete.  So all you need to show is that $C_c(\mathbb N,\mathbb R)$ is dense in these spaces with their respective norms.

Comment: can you elaborate and provide a proof?

Comment: I think after this hint, that you need to show what you have tried.

Comment: Here is my attempt at proving that $C_{c}(\Bbb{N}, \Bbb{R})$ is dense in $\mathit{l}^p$:

take any $f\in \mathit{l}^p$. since $\sum_{t=1}^\infty |f(t)|^p < \infty$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ s.t. $\sum_{t=N}^\infty |f(t)|^p < \epsilon$. define $f_{c}(t) = \{ f(t), t<N; 0\}$. we have that $f_{c}(t) \in C_{c}(\Bbb{N}, \Bbb{R})$, and $||f(t) - f_{c}(t)||_{p} = \sum_{t=N}^\infty |f(t)|^p < \epsilon$. So, $\forall f\in \mathit{l}^p$, $\exists f_{c}$ in any neighborhood of $f$ s.t. $f_c \in C_{c}(\Bbb{N}, \Bbb{R})$.

Comment: Montgomer-Smith is this proof correct? Are there any mistakes or incorrect claims that I make? Also, any chance you could link to a proof that $\mathit{l}^\mathit{p}$ are complete? I was able to find proofs for $L^\mathit{p}$ but not for $\mathit{l}^\mathit{p}$

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.  It also works for $c_0$.  As for completion, since $\ell^p$ is $L^p(\mathbb N)$ where $\mathbb N$ is the counting measure, you can quote that result.

Comment: Or use this.  http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~allaire/master/TD1withanswer.pdf  Use google with "little l p complete"